# Undefined value when using fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js, fs

I am using node.js and i am trying to read a folder and return the file.length, then i want to write the value on a txt file. The problem is that when i try to use fs.writeFile it creates a file that only contains the world ***undefined*** .

```
var length;
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, file) {
   length = file.length+1;
});
setTimeout(function(){
}, 1000);  
fs.writeFile('/public/images/value.txt', length, function(err) {
     if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
       }

     console.log("The file was saved!");
     console.log(length);
});
```

> console.log(length) returns 6

Comment: `readdir` and `writeFile` are async functions. You either need to put `fs.writeFile` inside the callback for readdir, or use promises to resolve. The issue is `writeFile` is being called before `readdir` is finished, and no, the setTimeout is not a good way to stop that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some errors in your you're handling asynchronous code.  Both `fs.readir()` and `fs.writeFile()` are asynchronous.  That means, the only way you know they are done is inside their callback.

```
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    let length = files.length + 1;
    fs.writeFile('/public/images/value.txt', length, function(err) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.log("The file was saved!");
        console.log(length);
    });
});

// fs.readdir() has not yet completed when this part of your code runs
// it will complete some time late and then call its callback
// similarly fs.writeFile() has not yet completed when this part of your code runs
```

So, if you want to use the result of `fs.readdir()`, then you should use it inside the callback.  If you want to know when `fs.writeFile()` is done and to count on its presence and being up-to-date, you can only do that in its callback.

In addition, `setTimeout()` is NOT blocking.  All it does is schedule a timer to fire sometime in the future while the rest of your code keeps running.  So, if you were going to use a `setTimeout()` here, you'd have to put the `fs.writeFile()` code inside the `setTimeout()` callback.  But, that's a hack and is not the recommended way to handle asynchronous code.  You should just put the `fs.writeFile()` inside the `fs.readdir()` callback and then things will be 100% reliable.

Asynchronous results MUST be used inside the actual callback that signifies completion of the async operation or in a function that you call from within that callback.

Comment: @george.angelop - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This a typical error when you´re dealing with asynchronous code. The reason why you´re getting undefined is because the first function hasn´t finished reading the directory when the fs.writefile function is executed, so at this time length is still undefined. Try putting the writefile function inside your setTimeout function. This should make it.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work. I also tried to delete the  fs.readdir function and i replaced it with var length=6; just to test it , but it has the same problem with undefined.

Comment: Are you in "use strict" mode?

Comment: It doesn't work no matter if i use "use strict" or not.

Comment: That's why I said the timeOut was a bad idea, it's not a async run around for waiting for code to execute